# Why is $r$ a function of $\theta$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, coordinate-systems, centripetal-force

I am reading "Key Points of Mechanics" by Haruo Yoshida.

He wrote $r$ was a function of $\theta$. (please see below.)

But if $\theta(t_0)=\theta(t_1)$ and $r(t_0) \neq r(t_1)$ for $t_0 \neq t_1$, $r$ is not a function of $\theta$.

Please explain why $r$ is a function of $\theta$.

> The equations of motion in a polar coordinate system are the following:
>
> $m (\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2) = f_r$,
>   $m(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})=f_{\theta}$.
>
> If $f_r := -\frac{GMm}{r^2}, f_{\theta}:=0$, then
>   $\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2 = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$,
>   $r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}=0$.
>
> $\frac{d}{dt}(r^2\dot{\theta}) = 2r\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r^2\ddot{\theta} = r(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta})=0$.
>
> So, $r^2\dot{\theta}$ is constant.
>   Let $h := r^2\dot{\theta}$.
>
> $\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2 = \ddot{r}-r(\frac{h}{r^2})^2 = \ddot{r}-\frac{h^2}{r^3} = -\frac{GM}{r^2}$.
>
> $r$ is a function of $\theta$ and the following equation holds:
>
> $\frac{d}{d\theta}(\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\theta})=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{GM}{h^2}$.

Comment: How does that prove r is not a function of $\theta$? r is a function of time also.

Comment: What's the problem? Your claim is right. But how does it affect the fact that r can be a function of theta? If your claim is right, r cannot be a function of theta. But your claim is not guaranteed to hold for every r.

Comment: On the contrary it can be said, if r is a function of theta then your claim is never true.

Comment: Also, do note that theta is not equal to theta+2pi .  Hence spiral motions can be perfectly represented by r as a function of theta.

Comment: Please edit the question to give some context so we know what this is about. Also, please edit the title so people can understand what is being asked about.

Answer (score 1):

You've got $r^2\dot{\theta}$ constant.  Unless that constant is zero, this means that $\dot{\theta}$ never changes sign, which means that $\theta$ is either always increasing or always decreasing as a function of $t$.  Therefore you never have to worry about the possibility that $\theta(t_0)=\theta(t_1)$ with $t_0\neq t_1$.

The only exception is where the constant value of $\dot{\theta}$ is zero, in which case the motion is all back and forth along a single radius.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have three variables, $r, \theta, t$. You are correct that r cannot be a function of $\theta $ if you limit the range of $\theta$ to for example $[0,2\pi]$. If you do not project to this interval then you can take $t$ as the independent variable and have $r$ depend on $t$ via $\theta $. This is a fairly standard approach to derive Kepler orbits.

Comment: r= sin(theta) ,  0<theta<2pi represents a circle. Not sure if your argument is valid.

Answer (score 0):

> Please explain why  is a function of

Unfortunately, there is not much content to the statement. Basically, both $\theta$ and $r$ are functions of $t$. And if $\theta$ is an invertable function then $t=\theta^{-1}(\theta(t))$ so $r=r(t)=r(\theta^{-1}(\theta(t)))$.

Now, we can write $R=(r \circ \theta^{-1})$ so then $r=R(\theta)$ shows that $r$ is a function of $\theta$

> But if (0)=(1) and (0)≠(1) for 0≠1,  is not a function of

Yes, you are correct. In this case $\theta$ is not invertable so $\theta^{-1}(\theta(t))=t$ does not exist and the above approach falls apart.

Comment: Your last paragraph ignores the fact that $\theta$ **is** invertible (unless it's constant).

Comment: I am not ignoring that fact at all. Look at the quoted text. It implies that $\theta$ is constant

Comment: No, the assumption in the quoted text does not imply that $\theta$ is a constant.  You also need the equation that says $r^2\dot{\theta}$ is constant.

Comment: Sure, conservation of angular momentum together with the quoted assumption imply that $\theta$ is constant. Even without conservation of angular momentum the quoted assumption alone means that $\theta$ is not invertable. My answer is correct as is and I am not ignoring anything. Not sure why you think I am. The assumption is a perfectly valid assumption, I simply chose to answer it as a valid assumption instead of rejecting the assumption as you did in your answer. I don’t have a problem with your approach, not sure why you have a problem with mine